# Sprite issue when responding to touch event in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have loaded two checkbox sprites on the screen. The image to load the sprite initially in an unchecked checkbox. Then I expect to click on one checkbox and replace the image with another checked checkbox image. The code I have written behaves very strangely where the checked checkbox image never appears.

I have two class properties:

```
var check1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "unchecked.png")
var check2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "unchecked.png")
```

I am calling generateCheckboxex() method from didMoveToView(view: SKView)

```
func generateCheckboxes()
{
    self.check1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.75, self.size.height * 0.84)
    self.check1.setScale(0.15)
    self.check1.name = "check1"
    self.addChild(self.check1)

    self.check2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.75, self.size.height * 0.75)
    self.check2.setScale(0.15)
    self.check2.name = "check2"
    self.addChild(self.check2)
}
```

This is my touchBegan method code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var touch = touches as!  Set<UITouch>
    var location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    // If next button is touched, start transition to second scene
    if node.name == "check1" {
        //self.check1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "checked.png")
        var texAction = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "checked.png"))
        self.check1.runAction(texAction)

        //self.check2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "checked.png")
        self.check2.runAction(texAction)
    }

    if node.name == "check2" {
        self.check1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "unchecked.png")
        self.check2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "checked.png")
    } 
}
```

Please help me and let me know if I'm approaching it in the wrong manner, thanks.

**EDIT:** Admins please close this question, this exact same code works for me now. Maybe it was an issue with the sprites themselves. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by strange? If the texture doesn't change what does it show instead?

Comment: The checked texture never appears. I have some label of questions as well, I took out the code for that part, but the label just disappears!

Comment: I tried your code and everything was OK. Click node1, both nodes turn checked. Click node2, node1 turns unchecked and node2 turns checked. Any difference from what you see on your side?

Comment: I tried it myself later and the exact same thing works now. That's why I was saying its strange behaviour. Thanks anyways guys!